# Как передать объект на websocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Начал разбираться в вебсокетами, и пробую написать небольшой чат
Ноду особо не знаю, для работы с базой на бекенде php-фреймворк, все запросы ajax в его контроллеры.

На клиентской части инициализирую подключение:

```
this.webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8084');
```

Соответственно вешаю обработчик:

```
this.webSocket.send(message);
```

За серверную часть ответственна нода(отдельный скрипт файл):

```
var WSServer = new WS.Server({port: 8084}); 
WSServer.on('connection', function (ws) { 
//Подписываемся на событие - получение сообщения
    ws.on('message', function (text) {
        console.log('Сообщение получено. Текст: ' + text);
```

На этом этапе все понятно. Подключаются пользователей в браузере, даже переписку ведут.

Но как в серверном файле идентифицировать подключенного пользователя?
Сейчас получается что все они пишут в один канал и их сообщения никак логически не разделяются.

Скажем если id группы пользователя который подключился в браузере 123 то и все сообщения сохранять в группу с 123. Это именно так я себе представляю механизм, если принцип другой подскажите как правильно?

> Для посылки данных используется метод socket.send(data). Пересылать
>   можно любые данные.

Это прописано в руководстве https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets#primer-brauzernogo-koda

При попытке передать в

```
websocket.send({
  userid : 1,
  group : 2,
  message: 3,
})
```

в логе на сервере я получаю `Сообщение получено. Текст: [object Object]`
Обратиться по своим ключам тоже не могу.

Как правильно делать и чего я не усвоил в этом вопросе?

Comment: «Пересылать можно любые данные.» — нет, learn.javascript.ru нагло врёт, написал там комментарий об этом. Передовать можно только или текст, или байты. Соответственно, данные любого другого типа необходимо предварительно перевести в текст, например с помощью json

Comment: сериализуй объект с помощью `JSON.stringify`